# Costs. Algorithm analysis. Algorithms in

Tags: algorithm

It is possible to state that the cost of an O(n²) algorithm will always be less than a cost of O(n).
Comment on the truth of the statement:

Comment: For an `O(x)` algorithm, the complexity (e.g. time or space complexity) grows like `x`. Maybe in your case it helps to draw the two functions `f(n) = n²` and `g(n) = n` and then derive if the statement is true or not?

Comment: How do you define cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Saying that an algorithm is O(n²) means that there is at least a case where the algorithm will take a quadratic number of operations to finish.

In a O(n) algorithm, the worst case will be linear, so for a big enough input, the worst case of a O(n²) algorithm will always take more operations than a O(n) algorithm.

```
O(n) = k * n + a
O(n²) = k2 * n² + k1 * n + b

so we wanna prove that there is a case that O(n) < O(n²)

k * n + a < k2 * n² + k1 * n + b
(k - k1) * n + (a - b) < k2 * n²
(k - k1) / k2 + (a - b) / (k2 * n) < n
```

We can see that, as `n` grows, the constants in the left side will stay the same or decrease, so there will be a point where O(n) < O(n²).